# Установка NetBeans, пакет не найден

Tags: java, windows, java-ee, ide, netbeans

Не могу установить Netbeans, переменная среда указана, но установка не начинается
[image]

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте установить с 8-ой версией Java. Возможно NetBeans просто не поддерживает 10-ю версию.

Answer (score 1):

Для установки и выполнения IDE NetBeans 8.2 требуется Java SE 8. [см. Требуемое программное обеспечение](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes_ru.html#req_sw)